# Looking for source: Max num of edges of graph with given number of vertices and given girth

Tags: graph-theory, extremal-graph-theory

In a paper I am reading, the author states:

"It is simple and well known that a graph of girth $g$ and $q$ vertices has at most $q^{1+(O(1)/g)}$ edges"

He says that a proof can be found on Extremal Graph Theory, by Bela Bollobas.

However, I do not have easy access to that book.

Could someone please direct me to a more common graph theory book that has this result or some equivalent result?

Comment: btw, this is a cross-post. I have tryed math.stackexchange first, because the question is a bit basic, but got no response

Comment: It must be this: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1850563/looking-for-source-max-num-of-edges-of-graph-with-given-number-of-vertices-and You should wait at least a few days before deciding to cross-post. Also: at each site where you post a question, always link to every other site where the same question is posted. (This means $n(n-1)$ links in all, if you have posted at $n$ sites.)

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you have a look at the excellent lecture notes of David Conlon, found at:

https://www.dpmms.cam.ac.uk/~dc340/Extremal-course.html

In particular you will be interested in Lectures 10 and 11, which contain an answer to your question.